# Hopf surface as an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles

I saw that the (primary) Hopf surface is an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{P}^1$. I want to see why. What I am thinking is by the Hopf fibration $S^1\to S^3\to S^2$, we can construct a fibration $S^1\times S^1\to S^3\times S^1\to S^2$ by taking the product of each fiber and $S^1$. And $S^3\times S^1$ is the smooth structure of the Hopf surface, $S^2$ is the smooth structure of $\mathbb{P}^1$, $S^1\times S^1$ is the smooth structure of the elliptic curve. I wonder if we can show this bundle map is holomorphic so that the fibration $S^1\times S^1\to S^3\times S^1\to S^2$ gives the claim that Hopf surface is an elliptic surface over $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Do I have to check the local formula to determine if the map $S^3\times S^1$ is holomorphic or is there an easier way to see it?

The primary Hopf surface I mean is the compact complex surface given by $\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z$ where $\gamma:(z_1,z_2)\mapsto (2z_1,2z_2)$ generates $\mathbb Z$. And it can be proved that it's diffeomorphic to $S^3\times S^1$.

Attempt: I am thinking maybe I can use the quotient manifold theorem. See the fiber as a complex Lie group, $T:=\mathbb C/(\mathbb Z+\tau\mathbb Z)$ and it acts on $\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z$ properly and freely, then we get a fiber bundle $\mathbb C/(\mathbb Z+\tau\mathbb Z)\to \mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z\to (\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z)/T$ and by the long exact sequence of homotopy groups we can see $(\mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z)/T$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$. And it's easy to see the action is free, so now the question is if the action is proper? And if so, then by the quotient manifold theorem, we get a holomorphic fiber bundle $T\to \mathbb C^2-\{0\}/\mathbb Z\to\mathbb P^1$

Comment: "**the** Hopf surface". There is no such thing. There are infinitely many Hopf surfaces, some of them are elliptic, some are not. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I have added the definition of the Hopf surface on my post.

Comment: Think about the map $p: \mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$ by sending $[z_1,z_2]\mapsto [z_1:z_2]$, clearly, it is surjective, determine the fiber $p^{-1}([z_1:z_2])$, which is $\{[az_1,az_2]\in\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}: a\in\mathbb{C}^*\}$, notice that this is  in fact $\mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{Z}$, the Hopf curve, hence it is an elliptic curve.